# How do I implement simple use-case[if/else] for some Intend in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, use-case

After taking some information from the user I want to **return some text** using those data. Like **If/else** statement. If this matches with this then I will return this. But I don't know where I can or how to **implement** this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: do you want such conditions execution after matching intent or before that?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into writing that code using [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services), which is typically implemented using a webhook or Dialogflow's built-in editor. You might, for example, do something like this:

```
function languageHandler(agent) {
    const language = agent.parameters.language;
    const programmingLanguage = agent.parameters.ProgrammingLanguages;
    if (language) {
        agent.add("Wow! I didn't know you knew ${language}");
    }
    else if (programmingLanguage) {
        agent.add("${programmingLanguage} is cool");
    } else {
        agent.add("What language do you know?")
    }
}
```

Comment: But how should I do that? Can you give me a example code or a guideline

Comment: The link I included in the answer contains several examples. I've added one.